# PHP SnapChat API error

Tags: php, api, github, snapchat

I am trying to use the third party SnapChat API from [this repository](https://github.com/JorgenPhi/php-snapchat).

Here is the PHP code that I am running.

```
<?php

require_once('src/snapchat.php');
$snapchat = new Snapchat('user', 'password');
print_r($snapchat);
die();
```

The result is `Snapchat Object ( [auth_token] => [username] => )`

I have created a new account and i have tried the script on a new server for change account/ip' but nothing append.

Do you know why i can't use this API today ? (*API worked the last 3 days*)

Comment: Was it working before? Are you sure you're giving it valid authentication credentials?

Comment: Yes, it worked there three days ago. And my authentication credentials are valids :/

Comment: I would guess they've changed their API - there is no official snapchat API so they can break it any time they see fit. You'll either need to wait for a dev to respond to your github issue or dig in to the lib your self (or hope someone comes along who already has)

Comment: I think snapchat change their API :/
But i hope they don't ...

Comment: Lot of ios app snapchat work, maybe i need to change the snapchat_agent ?

Comment: same here. anyone got a solution?

Comment: anyone get any update?

Comment: Same here getting error while login,
Notice: Undefined property: Snapchat::$cache in /var/www/html/snapchat_api/src/snapchat.php on line 233

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/html/snapchat_api/src/snapchat.php on line 233